# Mod_Rewrite wildcard's / appending

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make a global rule with a category on my website where something automatically gets added to the end of url.

An example:

www.websitename.com/category/page.html gets changed to www.websitename.com/category/page.html?somethingelse and anything subsequently which is www.websitename.com/category/* gets appended with ?somethingelse

I know I could do this with individual 301 redirects but is there a one rule fits all? as every time a new page is created currently, a new redirect would have to be made.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.*.html)$ category/$1?somethingelse
```

This means that every URL that starts with category and ends with html will be rewritten to add ?somethingelse at the end. Examples:

```
http://www.websitename.com/category/foo.html => http://www.websitename.com/category/foo.html?somethingelse
http://www.websitename.com/category/bar.html => http://www.websitename.com/category/bar.html?somethingelse
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it but it just isn't doing anything which seems very strange. the functionality you've listed is exactly what I need. I'm appending with "?sort_by=product&sort_order=asc" I assume none of the special characters would make it not work?