# Automatically rewrite GET vars

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get, url-routing

This has probably been asked before somewhere. However, after searching for quite some time, I can not figure this out.

I am creating a small routing engine for my php site. I want to be able to make it as dynamic and flexible as possible. Right now, I have all URLs go to my router file, internally and it parses the URL for the correct page.

I want to be able to automatically convert all GET parameters into some predefined format. I was wondering if this is possible:

From:
    example.com/page.php?param=val&param=val...

To:

```
example.com/page/param/val/param/val...
```

The key being that I don't want to hard code matches. Ideally I wouldn't need to know how many GET cars there are or what they are but instead automatically convert any into a predefined format as above. The URI would then be passed into my router which would then parse it as needed. Also, the path to the page could be several "subdirectories" in, for example

```
example.com/account/register.php?action=something

example.com/account/register/action/something
```

**TLDR**

*Can mod_rewrite automatically convert all GET parameters into some predefined format like page/param/val/param/val or page/param:val/param:val?*

**UPDATE**

To clarify my question/ I understand how I can use regular expressions and what not to match url's. My question is whether I can set up some rule that will convert the query string into a predefined format without knowing how many parameters there are or what page they are for beforehand.

Comment: sure - you can use regular expressions in `RewriteRule` directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of using mod_rewrite, you could loop through the $_GET array in your index.php, and do something like:

```
$url = '';
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
   $url .= $key . '/' . $value . '/';
}


header ("Location: http://www.mysite.com/" . $url);
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, but if possible using mod_rewrite directly?

Answer (score 0):

see similar problem for inspiration on how to use regular expressions:

[Mod_Rewrite wildcard's / appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470373/mod-rewrite-wildcards-appending)

Comment: I get regular expressions but I am wondering how I can do this without knowing how many GET vars there are? The question you've linked appends some pre-defined values to the end of a matched url. I basically want to have it rewrite the query string into a different format (without knowing the number of params in the query string)

Comment: for rewriting arbitrary number of vars see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122022/mod-rewrite-with-an-unknown-number-of-variables